# Need to drop the oldest record (can be multiple "oldest records")

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, date

My dataset looks like this:

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 29/07/2022 |
| 111 | 30/03/2022 |
| 111 | 30/03/2022 |
| 111 | 30/03/2022 |
| 111 | 02/08/2022 |
| 222 | 08/11/2022 |
| 222 | 07/07/2022 |
| 222 | 11/11/2022 |
| 222 | 10/07/2022 |

I need to drop the oldest record per ID but keeping all the others, the problem is that I may have various "oldest records" with the same date. I'm looking for something like this:

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 29/07/2022 |
| 111 | 02/08/2022 |
| 222 | 08/11/2022 |
| 222 | 11/11/2022 |
| 222 | 10/07/2022 |

I tried sorting and dropping duplicates, which almost worked in every case (ID=222) but when it comes to ID=111, with various "oldest records" to drop, it didn't function as I expected.

Comment: What didn't function as you expected? What happened instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```py
def discard_min(g):
    return g[g > g.min()]

newdf = df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].apply(discard_min).droplevel(1).reset_index()
>>> newdf
    ID       DATE
0  111 2022-07-29
1  111 2022-08-02
2  222 2022-11-08
3  222 2022-11-11
4  222 2022-07-10
```

Reproducible setup for the above:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[111, '29/07/2022'], [111, '30/03/2022'], [111, '30/03/2022'],
     [111, '30/03/2022'], [111, '02/08/2022'], [222, '08/11/2022'],
     [222, '07/07/2022'], [222, '11/11/2022'], [222, '10/07/2022']],
    columns=['ID', 'DATE'])
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```